# Load cache on all application servers using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, caching, automation

I am trying to create an automated way of performing a small journey on my website after we restart the servers so that it loads everything in the Cache before the actual customer comes in. I have already implemented the code for it but what it does is just hit one server/node and get the cache on that server. What I want is it should hit each of the 4 nodes one by one.

I have given a thought and I think we can do it by using cookies. So

1. Run the program and get the sessionID from cookie.
2. That sessionID contain the node number.
3. Check the node and loop the same program to hit on another 3 nodes.

Node Example:

> 354654-node-1,2,3,4

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Shashank\\Java\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.example.com/new");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("consent_prompt_submit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("postcode")).sendKeys("12345");
    driver.findElement(By.className("button-container")).click();

    String cookieValue = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sessID").getValue();
    String cookiePath = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sessID").getPath();
    Date expiryDate = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sessID").getExpiry();
    boolean isSecure = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sessID").isSecure();
    System.out.println("Cookie value for sessID : " + cookieValue);
    System.out.println("Cookie Path for sessID : " + cookiePath);
    System.out.println("Cookie Expiry for sessID : " + expiryDate);
    System.out.println("Cookie Secure for sessID : " + isSecure);

    // I need to write code here to invoke another session like above but it should hit another node

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Chromedriver creates a fresh chrome instance every time in your %temp%. That means, when you visit your website using selenium, you are not visiting it from the chrome instance your customer generally uses to visit your website.

So, the easiest way to accomplish what you want to accomplish is to specify the default chrome profile path (the one which your customer is using) as "[user-data-dir](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)" chrome option. This way, you will be visiting your website from the correct chrome profile.

2) Regarding the multiple node visits, what you can do is to visit all 4/5/whatever nodes you want to visit in separate chrome tabs.

- Use Actions class to open a new Tab by sending keys 'Ctrl + T'
- Get list of tabs using driver.getWindowHandles()
- Go to last tab using driver.switchTo().window(...) and visit another node

If you want to visit those nodes in different sessions, or if you do not want the sessions to interfere, then you may need to kill and reopen the chrome instance. You can use user-data-dir in only one chrome instance at a time.

If you are referring nodes as node in selenium grid system, then you need to specify different chrome profile path and different automation code for different nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: - Hey Ballal thanks for your response. I was actually able to work it  using session cookies. I was able to force my browser to hit the specific server which i want using the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no session, the application will give you a new session and most likely select a different node randomly. So the KISS approach would be to just run your script multiple times and clear the cookies via `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();` before each new run.

Doing it this way you need no knowledge about the number of nodes that are currently existing (which may change). To end your script you could collect the node names you have seen each run and if no new node shows up after three runs you can terminate.